# Loop inside a Row widget to create a list of TEXT

Tags: loops, flutter, text, widget, row

Someone can help -> loop inside a row... or a solution similar.
medicamentos.items[i].frequencia is like **n times a day**, so 24/frequencia gives me **the hours to add** to the medicamentos.items[i].horaInicio

````
         children: <Widget>[
         for (var i = 0; i < 24; i + (24 /medicamentos.items[i].frequencia))
          {
            Text(  DateFormat(DateFormat.HOUR24_MINUTE, 'pt_Br')
                   .format(medicamentos.items[i].horaInicio
                   .add(Duration(hours: i))),

                                          ),
                                        },
                                    ], ```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just create a seperate list of Text widgets, and then supply the list to the children parameter of the list like this:

```
Widget myRow(){
  List<Widget> children = [];

  for(int i=0; i<4; i++){
    children.add(Text("Text$i"));
  }

  return Row(
    children: children,
  );
}
```

Then you can add the myRow() widget to the tree like any other widget.

Comment: yeah, I took it out... in fact, I changed all the implementation because i needed something else too. It´s working fine.
Thanks <3

Answer (score 2):

I am quite confusing about how `frequencia` is worked here. I assume that it mean that number of something that happens in each hour?

But one thing that certain is you can just use a `List.generate()` instead of loop it like this. For example:

```
Row(
   children: List.generate(item.length, (i){
      return Text(
         item[i]
      );
   },)
),
```

Hope this is an answer that you are looking for.

Comment: This is a cleaner way to do it compared to the for-loop solution.